# Getting YouTube Content ID API

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube Content ID API is not showing up on my api console, I already made sure my channel was partnered, I also linked it the CMS account, everything is setup correctly but, when I go to the API console it does not show it. The channel I'm uploading the videos to is a brand account of the main email, is that the problem? if so how can I fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to YouTube Content ID API you first need to apply here.
https://www.youtube.com/content_id_signup?internalcountrycode=GB

You must be a partner to apply.